# Custom posts - tag pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, tags

I'm using the following code to output the custom posts that belongs to a `tag`:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
    if(is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
        $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
        if($post_type) :
            $post_type = $post_type;
        else:
            $post_type = array('btp_work'); // replace cpt to your custom post type
            $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
        endif;
    return $query;
    }
}
```

It works well if the `tag` has less than 10 posts (my pagination settings are on 10 posts), for example if I go to `mysite.com/tag/cars` it shows the custom posts that the tag `cars` has.

The problem is when there are a lot of custom posts associated to a `tag`. The `tag` page adds pagination but there is no custom posts showing:

[image]

Any idea what could be the problem here?

It seems WP knows how many posts are since it shows four pages and creates the pagination but it's strange no custom posts on any of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a couple of flaws which I'm not going to go into detail now. Here is a short list

- `pre_get_posts` is an action
- On any type of archive page you need to make sure you only target the main query and the front end when using `pre_get_posts`
- Your syntax is very hard to debug and not supported by most code editors. Although `if (): else : endif;` is valid php, it is not recommended due the trouble debugging it. Use proper curlies like `if () { } else { }`
- Most of your code does not make much sense. Please see my code and compare it with yours

You can rewrite your code as follows

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (     !is_admin() // Make sure you only target the front end 
          && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
          && $q->is_tag() // Only target the tag pages
    ) {
        $q->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'btp_work' ) ); // Change as necessary
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Pieter, works perfectly! Nice explanation also :)